# How to make a list iterator that starts at the end of the list

Tags: java, list, iterator, listiterator

I have a homework question that asks me to make a list iterator that starts at the end of the list. I have no idea how to do this. Here is the code

```
public class LinkedListTester7
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i = i + 2)
            list.add(i) ;
        //-----------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 3
        // 1. make a list iterator that starts at the end of the list ;
        ListIterator<Integer> litr = list.listIterator();
        //2.  while hasPrevious ;
        while (litr.hasPrevious()) {
            //3. print what is returned by previous() followed by a blank without a newline  
            System.out.println(litr.previous()+ " ");
        }
        //-----------------End here. Please do not remove this comment.     Reminder: no changes outside the todo regions.
        System.out.println() ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Read the java.util.List API documentation...

```
ListIterator<Integer> litr = list.listIterator(list.size());
```

Comment: Sorry, I am fairly new to using Java. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Aactually a  [A ListIterator has no current element; its cursor position always lies between the element that would be returned by a call to previous() and the element that would be returned by a call to next().](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html)

If you want the first call to next()/previous() to return the last element you could use [listIterator(int index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator%28int%29) and pass it list.size() -1 if you want to iterate forward or list.size() if you want to iterate backward.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LinkedListTester7
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i = i + 2)
            list.add(i) ;
        //-----------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 3
        // 1. make a list iterator that starts at the end of the list ;
        ListIterator<Integer> litr = list.listIterator(list.size());
        while (litr.hasPrevious()) {
            System.out.println(litr.previous()+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println() ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I think this might be the code you're looking for:

```
for (int i = litr.size(); i >= 0; i--) {
    System.out.println(litr.get(i));
}
```

Basically it starts at the end of the array and prints the results from last to first.

This is what's starting at the END of the ArrayList:

```
i = litr.size();
```

i-- counts backwards through the array until it reaches 0.

Comment: He is asking about a linked list, and accessing it by index is bad idea